# MultiView FXML Project on iOS using Gluon-mobile and Java9

Tags: ios, java-9, gluon-mobile

Creating a completely new MultiView FXML Project and then adding the Java9 necessities in Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven{
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.5'
    }
}

...

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.0-jdk9'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'

    // Added because of javax.annotation.PostConstruct Java9 issues
    compile group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.2.6'    
}
```

leads to **[SUB] Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stage must be showing before making the Dialog visible.**

[full console log](https://gist.github.com/powerworr/0920440d92b926ed398d20e61c9f52f6)

The project runs as expected on Desktop and Android, but not on iOS simulator and device. I have tried many things, but since this error comes on newly created projects leads me to believe that it's something caused by the interplay of gluon-mobile and Java9.

*Bonus:* Changing only the *jfxmobile-plugin* to 2.0.18 fails even compiling with:

> [15:08:15:141] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: Still compiling... 8823
>   classes left.
>     [15:08:25:143] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: Still
>   compiling... 4152 classes left.
>     [15:08:34:389] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: halfway done round 0 
>     java.lang.StackOverflowError
>        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:642)
>        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
>        at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
>        at com.gluonhq.higgs.DependencyGraph.visitReachableNodes(DependencyGraph.java:170)

Comment: Can you try with `compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'` instead of `'jaxws-api'`?

Comment: @JoséPereda [Same console log](https://gist.github.com/powerworr/5cb24ae8b190eb743b6ca76eee0625b0)

Comment: Can you try again 2.0.18 but using for Charm Down version `3.7.2`?

Comment: @JoséPereda It was already set to `3.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for me:

- Using Java 9, and NetBeans 9 (beta version) with Gluon IDE plugin 2.6.2, I've created a Gluon project (multi view with FXML). Of course, this will work with other IDEs as well.
- I've checked that the gradle wrapper was using 4.3.1 (or superior).
- I've modified the `build.gradle` file to use Gluon VM with jfxmobile 2.0.18:

`build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.18'
    }
}
```

and updated the dependencies:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.0-jdk9'
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
}
```

- Then I just deployed the project to my iOS device without any issue.

Note that it may be convenient to clean your `~/.gvm` cache, as it might contain classes from older versions that shouldn't be used anymore. Of course, you should also clean your project `./gradle` and `/build` folders.

Comment: Can it be that I am using Gluon IDE plugin 2.5.3? I see only this version in the Eclipse Marketplace. NetBeans however seems to have [2.6.2](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57602) and IntelliJ even [2.6.3](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7864-gluon-plugin).

Comment: No, that's the latest version as well. Once you have a valid build.gradle file, the plugin version doesn't really matter.