# Gluon VM StackOverflowError

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

Similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514146/multiview-fxml-project-on-ios-using-gluon-mobile-and-java9). But anything mentioned there did not help.

I am using latest Apache Netbeans (incubator-netbeans-linux-424-on-20180428) (MacOS 10.12.6) with JDK 9.0.4 and Gluon Plugin 2.7.0.
Created a new Project with template "Single View Project on Gluon VM".
gradle version 4.3.1

I tried:

```
org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.19 and 2.0.20 (did clean gvm folder)
```

After couple minutes compiling, I get:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.  
16:52:30.811 [ERROR] [system.err] [16:52:30:810] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: Still compiling... 0 classes left.  
16:52:30.817 [ERROR] [system.err] [16:52:30:817] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: halfway done round 0   
16:52:31.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6121746432}  
16:52:31.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6121746432}  
16:52:31.593 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 4294967296, Committed: 3221225472}  
16:52:31.598 [ERROR] [system.err] java.lang.StackOverflowError
16:52:31.605 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)  
16:52:31.605 [ERROR] [system.err]   at  java.base/java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:596)  
16:52:31.605 [ERROR] [system.err]   at  java.base/java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:204)  
16:52:31.606 [ERROR] [system.err]   at  com.gluonhq.higgs.**DependencyGraph**.visitReachableNodes(DependencyGraph.java:168)  
...
```

There is an ./build/gvm/GluonApplicationApp.app
But this app fails to install manually.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See point #4 of the list of [iOS prerequisites](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/README.md#ios), try it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -Xss2m did work.

Thanks José